# Person titles co-referencing in one text

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gate, information-extraction

If I have in the same txt "president of the united states" and "Park Obama", how could I extract the title "President of the United States" as a name entity referring to the "Obama" name entity?

What I have done is:
I add "president of united state" to the person names list in the gazetteer and it annotated it as a person but without co-referencing to Barak Obama.

Example of the text:

> Barack Obama is an American politician serving as the 44th President
>   of the United States. Born in Honolulu, Hawaii, Obama is a graduate of
>   Columbia University and Harvard Law School.

Another example: How could I refer to Prince of Wales as  Prince Charles that they are the same person in the following text?

> The Prince of Wales is the Queen's eldest son and first in line to the
>   throne. On 29 July 1981 he married Lady Diana Spencer, who became the
>   Princess of Wales. The couple had two sons, William and Harry. They
>   later separated and their marriage was dissolved in 1996. On 31 August
>   1997, the Princess was killed in a car crash in Paris. Prince Charles
>   married Camilla Parker Bowles on 9 April 2005. As heir to the throne,
>   his main duties are to support the Queen in her royal commitments.

In general, if I need to resolve any title to its original name entities.